# How to serialize this json string?

Tags: json, json.net

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = @"{'status':0, 'array':[[+8613480610496,1905091845400259790]], 'success':1, 'fail':0}";

        var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(str); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I found the Newtonsoft JSON.NET deserialize library for C#. I tried to use it as follows:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("status", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("success", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fail", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Fail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("array",TypeNameHandling =TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public object Array { get; set; }
}
```

How to serialize this json string?

Answer (score 0):

The process you followed looks ok, but there is something wrong with your string.

For the property `array`, it's type is `object` in your Response class, but in your string, it is `[[+8613480610496,1905091845400259790]]` which is an array.